# Websites won't load (empty response) on any browser on every client on site if "https://" is not specified

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, https

I am observing a client-side but site-wide problem when trying to access websites at my location:

Websites **won't** load if I type in any [URI](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) in my browser if I don't specify the *scheme* (https:// mostly).
If I open a site by only typing in the search bar, starting a google search and clicking the link it loads properly.

As an example, typing:

- "web.de" won't load the site, yielding an ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE on Chrome.
- "https://web.de" will load the site normally.

This happens on every client (tested on WS2012 and WS2008, heard the problem also exists on all existing Windows 10 clients), **using any browser**, at my site.

- Chrome will quickly issue an ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error.
- Firefox says "Error: Connection interrupted"
- IE will add a http:// to my domain.com. The site won't load with http however and there is no redirect to https. The error will be "The site cannot be displayed". (translated from german)

**Edit:** If I have once typed in the full address, including both *scheme* and *authority*, I won't have to specify the scheme on following attempts.

Thinking this must be a DNS issue I restarted the service on the W2K8-R2 that I use but this doesn't solve the problem.

**Edit:** It seems like something disables or prevents redirects from http to https system-wide for all systems in this physical location. All devices that exhibit the problem share an organizational unit of my domain (since they're all ordered by site location). Other OUs don't have the problem.

**Edit:** 
I just tested ard.de. The site won't load if I type

- http://ard.de,
- http://www.ard.de, or
- https://ard.de but WILL load if I type:
- https://www.ard.de.

HTTP sites won't load at all and https sites will load only if I specify.

Since I have not set up this system I feel a bit out of my depth and since this problem seems very specific I want to ask what could possibly cause this.

**EDIT/SOLUTION:**
I hesitate to make this a proper answer but my mistake was trusting my ISP. Their DNS had/has some defect. The solution involved setting an alternate DNS-Server (e.g. 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8) on the Domain-Controller. Please contact me if this is supposed to be made an actual answer.

Comment: Is there a proxy server involved?

Comment: @duenni I just checked, no, but thank you for asking :)

Comment: http://web.de is not working, it redirects automatically to https://

Comment: @Overmind The redirect won't take place though. All browsers will just error out. I sadly don't know who is usually responsible for the "domain.com" redirect to the https link but these redirects to common sites that worked before, don't work any more.

Comment: Which browser is affected? Is there an AD domain in place? Check GPO settings. Is there an antivirus solution in place? Check this/disable temporarily.

Comment: Try another browser and see if the same behaviour presents itself, try firefox, for instance. Google chrome is well known for it's paranoic adherence to some standards like HSTS that might break some websites.

Comment: @Marcel I tried this with Chrome, Firefox and IE. As stated above the problem exists in any browser. IE will add http:// to a domain that I typed in, in this case amd.com. This will not load the site (due to HSTS maybe?). I am not redirected to HTTPS however. I have to type it out beforehand.
Sadly I don't know what GPO would do this but I'll check it out. Yes there is an AD in place. The antivirus cannot be disabled.

Comment: I doubt there is a GPO for all browsers, so my guess is antivirus or proxy. Ask your av admins to disable the antivirus solution temporarily.

Comment: Works for me from both Opera an IE 11. Something else seems to prevent the redirect.

Comment: @Overmind This is a problem specific to the infrastructure at my site. It is a "client-side" issue, not a serverside one. Some misconfiguration or defective hard- or software is causing the issue and I'm trying to find out what it is or even could be since I have no leads.

Comment: 1. Is your web server configured to redirect non-TLS connections (i.e. http) to https for sites that should be secure, and vice versa? 2. Is your web server configured to redirect the client to www.yourdomain.tld if they only enter yourdomain.tld?

Comment: the problem concerned every website. It was as I feared a DNS issue. The ISP had issues with theirs. As soon as an alternate, functioning DNS server was set, clients could resolve the addresses again. Sadly this problem as well as my solution turned out to be specific to my site so I hesitate to make it an actual, broadly valid answer.

Comment: I realise you have already stated no proxy server is involved, but I think you may be wrong. There could be a transparent proxy on port 80 that you are not fully aware of. A good test for this is to try and hit a site that you know is not listening on port 80, for example, http://8.8.8.8/ (IP of Google DNS) which should fail with a timeout, because Google have firewalled all protocols destined to that IP, except DNS. If you're getting an error which is indicating a "connection reset" when trying that, something is intercepting requests towards that port aka a transparent proxy.